# How can I align these search filters horizontally?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to align the search filters at https://www.violinschool.org/video-testing/

so that they appear horizontally instead of vertically.

What would be the best way to do this? I am reading about an 'inline block' using CSS but not sure if this is the best solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep inline-block is what you need, from looking at your markup you need to target html elements with the class `form-item`:

```
.form-item{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please add below css

```
form.wpv-filter-form.js-wpv-filter-form.js-wpv-filter-form-23679-TCPID23680.js-wpv-form-full.js-wpv-dps-enabled.js-wpv-ajax-results-enabled{
   display:flex;
 }

 .js-wpv-filter-trigger {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px !important;
 }
```

if you get any problem feel free to ask. Thanks

Comment: flex is great but some older browsers don't support it so if I use it I also use inline-block as a fallback. Also it's best to avoid using !important